# Can't access resource group in Azure, while having Contributor role for it

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I've been given access to a resource group in Azure, but still get 401 page while trying to access it or any resource in that resource group. I have role assigned to me only in a resource group, not subscription (maybe this can be the reason?)

- Type of my user: Guest
- Role for a resource group: Contributor

**Contributor** role gives full access, except ability to assign roles to other users.
Also, according to docs

> Guests can be added to administrator roles, which grant them full read
> and write permissions

What can be the problem?

This is the page I get when trying to access resource group or any of it resource:

[image: No access to resource page]

Answer (score 0):

> Azure Resource Manager sometimes caches configurations and data to improve performance. When you assign roles or remove role assignments, it can take up to 30 minutes for changes to take effect. If you are using the Azure portal, Azure PowerShell, or Azure CLI, you can force a refresh of your role assignment changes by signing out and signing in. If you are making role assignment changes with REST API calls, you can force a refresh by refreshing your access token.

Source: [Troubleshoot Azure RBAC - Role assignment changes are not being detected](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/troubleshooting#role-assignment-changes-are-not-being-detected)

Another option would be to visit the [preview portal](https://preview.portal.azure.com). Since this is a different website, you will get a new token which reflects the latest state.